# MVC Testing Spring Boot Mocking Keycloak Token

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, keycloak

I'm trying to do a MVC-Unittest for my with keycloak secured API.

Using https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons, and according to the example the test should work just fine.

test:

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = StudentController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Import({ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig.class,
        KeycloakSecurityConfig.class})
public class StudentControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StudentService service;

    @MockBean
    private StudentRepository repository;

    //TODO: Fix keycloak bug
    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth(
            authorities = { "USER", "AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL" },
            id = @IdTokenClaims(sub = "42"),
            oidc = @OidcStandardClaims(
                    email = "test@testing.com",
                    emailVerified = true,
                    nickName = "TesterNickName",
                    preferredUsername = "testName"),
            accessToken = @KeycloakAccessToken(
                    realmAccess = @KeycloakAccess(roles = { "TESTER" }),
                    authorization = @KeycloakAuthorization(
                            permissions = @KeycloakPermission(rsid = "toto", rsname = "truc", scopes = "abracadabra"))),
            privateClaims = @ClaimSet(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "foo", value = "bar")))
    public void shouldTest() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/students/test")).andReturn();
        assertEquals("abc", result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
keycloak:
  realm: xxx
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8081/auth
  ssl-required: external
  resource: client-interface
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  credentials:
    secret: xxx
  bearer-only: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

I'm getting following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:39)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
[...]
```

Any idea how to fix?

Greetings,
rosario

Comment: If you had linked this question in the issue as asked,it might have been answered faster... https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/issues/11#issuecomment-670365507

Comment: Do not esitate to comment why my answer doesn't solve your problem (or accept it...)

Answer (score 0):

RTFM

According to the stack-trace, adapter config is null in `KeycloakDeploymentBuilder`.
After a few hops up, it appears that it is not injected in `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver`.

As stated in my [lib main readme](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons): "Because of a regression from 9.0.2 to 12.0.0, you'll have to implement a work-around as shown in KeycloakSpringBootSampleApp"

And in the sample linked there:

```java
    // Work-around https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-14520 until keycloak 12.0.0
    @Configuration
    public class SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {

        private KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment;

        private AdapterConfig adapterConfig;

        @Autowired
        public SpringBootKeycloakConfigResolver(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
            this.adapterConfig = adapterConfig;
        }

        @Override
        public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {
            if (keycloakDeployment != null) {
                return keycloakDeployment;
            }

            keycloakDeployment = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);

            return keycloakDeployment;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this related with unit tests?

Comment: The fix I refer to in the answer you comment is for a regression in keycloak between 9.0.2 and 12.0.0. We are now passed 15 and the problem is long gone. If your comment refers to the lib itself, it's designed to work with MockMvc (or web test client) => unit tests